# how to search an xml file for a string and get the line number for the same in java

Tags: java, xml, search, line-numbers

i'm new to java and i need to search for a string under a tag and get its line number(element number) as well. Any suggestion on how to get it done.Any links and code is much appreciated ,thanks

Comment: read file line by line & search the text each line, get the line number.